# AWS Device Farm - Disable tutorials on devices

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

I am doing automated tests [Android / Appium Java JUnit] with the AWS Device Farm service, but they are interrupted by the use tutorials that appear on the devices, for example, the tutorial of how to use the camera. I want to know if there is a way to disable the tutorials of the use of the device. Thanks.

Comment: You should write to AWS support for help, I'm pretty sure they are aware of it and can suggest smth but would not read StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

I work for the AWS Device Farm team.

We detected and root caused this issue where a one-time tutorial popup appears on some phone's camera apps. We've corrected it, so feel free to try again and let us know if this problem is still affecting you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is also a script you can run from this AWS forum post

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=294719

> Hi,
>   I'm so sorry this keeps happening to you. We do currently only have the dismissal running on some devices like the Samsung S9, and are going to be enabling it for other devices soon, in the coming weeks. What I can do now is provide you a script to verify that theyre dismissed yourself at the beginning of your test. If you're using "custom environment mode", add the following 2 lines to the pre-test section of your test spec file:
>
> curl https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/aws-devicefarm-support/chrome_initialization_and_popup_detection.py -o chrome_initialization_and_popup_detection.py
>   - python chrome_initialization_and_popup_detection.py -v --retries 2 --output-dir $DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH/popup_dismissal
>
> This will run our popup dismissal script in your own code to verify that any device you run on gets all popups dismissed. It shouldn't be necessary for some devices like the S9, but just in case any do happen to creep up, this will dismiss them for you. I'll also double-check on our end why some popups like the S9 popup aren't getting dismissed properly.